# How to test if your app only works on ios7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I want my app to be unavailable to devices with IOS6 and lower. I followed what others were saying online and did two steps:

1. I changed the Deployment Target under General
   [image]
2. I changed the Base SDK under Build Settings
   [image]

However when I build from xcode or archive onto an iOS6 device my app still works. Did I do this wrong or is this a problem with my testing?

Comment: With a Deployment Target of 7.0 you can't run the app on an iOS device with iOS 6.x or earlier. Make sure the Deployment Target for the target (not just the project) is correct.

Comment: @casper The deployment target settings for the target may be different than for the project. Check both.

Comment: thanks that worked! I only changed it on target and did not change it for project.

Comment: The target is what matters. If the target was correct, the project's setting doesn't matter.

Comment: That is odd then. Right after I changed the project's settings is when it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Deployment Target like it's in picture below: 
[image]